# What is the difference between MD5 computeHash(Stream) and computeHash(byte[])

Tags: c#, .net, hash, md5

This has been a problem for a few people I've seen but most have been about text enconding problems. This is a purely binary problem. Here is some sample code.

```
MD5 md5Bytes  = MD5.Create() ;
MD5 md5Stream = MD5.Create() ;
var random    = new Random();

var bytes     = new byte[ 4096*2 ] ;
random.NextBytes(bytes);    
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes) ;

stream.Position = 0 ;

var bytesHash   = md5Bytes.ComputeHash(bytes);
var streamHash  = md5Stream.ComputeHash(stream);

for (int i = 0; i < bytesHash.Length; ++i)
  if ( bytes[i] != streamHash[i] )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Different content " + i);
    break;
  }
```

When I run this, to my surprise I get different results. Can somebody explain what's going on here shouldn't a MD5 of a byte array give the same results as a stream of identical content?

Comment: Tempted to close this as off-topic due to it just being a typo. I'd *strongly* encourage you to always put braces in for loops though, even when the body is just a single statement.

Comment: This is a good example of how debugging can solve problems. If you had a breakpoint in VS instead of writing code to do it, it'd be easier to look at the right variables.

Answer (score 8):

You're comparing data to a hash, so of course it's not the same; the comparison should be:

```
if (bytesHash[i] != streamHash[i])
```

And now it gives the same results, as expected ;)